# A brick made a dent in the hood of the car

Tags: sentence-construction

I was wondering if you could tell me if the bold part of the following sentence seem to be redundant or somehow weird and unnatural to you or not:

> - A brick **fell down from a building and** made a dent in the hood of the car.

Comment: To me, the "down" isn't necessary. "fell from the building" sounds cleaner to my ear, though what you have isn't wrong. Also, typically "dented" is used more than "made a dent in," though again, what you have isn't wrong.

Comment: Nothing grammatically weird or unnatural, but the brick's falling "from a  building" is a little uncanny. Did the brick get knocked off the roof of the building, by a worker, say, or did it become dislodged from the facade of the building? Was it tossed out a window?

Comment: No, it's not an adverbial phrase, and it doesn't modify anything.

Comment: @lurker The "brick" is the subject of the sentence, it doesn't modify the verb. This is a compound sentence with one subject - the brick - and two verbs, "fell" and "made".

Answer (score 2):

> A brick fell down from a building and made a dent in the hood of the car.

This is a compound sentence. Each half tells us something that the other does not. We can see this by breaking it apart.

> A brick fell down from a building. [It] made a dent in the hood of the car.

From the first, we see where the brick originated. It was not thrown by someone passing by or kicked up by the tires of a passing truck - it fell from a neighboring building. (*How* that happened - the cause - is not mentioned, nor is a concrete definition of *which* building it fell from.)

From the second, we see the result. The brick - the same one as in the first sentence, so we do not repeat "A brick" - dented the car hood. This is completely independent from its origin.

The distinction between "a brick" and "the brick" is important. In the first sentence, it is non-specific. "Of all of the bricks that make up this building, *one* of them fell." The only way we could use "the brick" here is if there were only one brick on the entire building.

In the second sentence, we would use "it" or "the brick" to link it to the previous sentence. At this point it *is* a specific brick - the one that fell.

As other posts have mentioned, the only (possibly) redundant information is "down", since things generally do not fall "up". However, this could be a rhetorical device rather than a physics lesson.

Answer (score 0):

More concise: **"A falling brick dented the hood of the car."**

"Dented" in the past tense implies the falling action is done.
"Down" is unnecessary in "fell down" here because bricks don't fall in any other direction.
"From a building" is also likely to be implied from context, but is odd because it's not clear if the brick used to be part of the building or not (see TRomano's comment).  You could still add this phrase after "brick" (and maybe even add "nearby" before "building" if you want to emphasize this is the only reason the building is relevant) if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**"A brick fell from a building at [address of building] and made a dent in the hood of my car,"** is just fine, since there is no way for you to know if it was thrown or dropped spontaneously. You might also want to add, **"I wasn't present when it happened but noticed the damage when I returned to my car at approximately [time/date]."** Hopefully, your insurance company will accept this answer and cover your loss.

Answer (score -1):

Your question potentially revolves around the use of **a** versus **the**

> ..fell down from **a** building and...

Makes it **indefinite** as to **which** building the brink fell from i.e. **a random building**.  However, it is usually obvious **from where** the brick fell, so

> ...fell down from **this** building and...
>   ...fell down from **that** building and...
>   ...fell down from **the** building and...

would sound more natural and associates a **particular** building with the action, also the listener might be interested which building **supplied the brick**.

In a similar way, a native speaker would also say

> We were hit by **a** storm
>   We got wet by **the** rain

but not

> We got wet by **a** rain

which makes the usage related to **countable** and **uncountable** things